# Update children nodes with PowerShell doesn't reflect in SharePoint GUI

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to update a node title on my SharePoint site with PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://dev:18792/sites/devsite/"

foreach ($webs in $web.Webs)
{

$nodes = $webs.Navigation.QuickLaunch
foreach ($node in $nodes)
{
    $nodeTitle = $node.Title
    if ($nodeTitle.ToString().Contains("First node"))
    {
        foreach ($nodeChild in $node.Children) {

            $nodeChildTitle = $nodeChild.Title

            if ($nodeChildTitle.ToString().Contains("Original childnode title")) {

                $nodeChild.Title = "Changed title"
                $nodeChild.Update()
                Write-Host "done."
            }
        }

    }
    $webs.Dispose()
}
$web.Dispose()
}
```

If I try it a second time and change

```
.Contains("Original childnode title")
```

to:

```
.Contains("Changed title")
```

It does enter that if statement, but the changes is not visible in the GUI.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Could it maybe be because you have the Publishing features activated? Manipulating the quick launch in a publishing site is a bit different. Here's some sample C# code:

```
 PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(oWeb);
 SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes;
 foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
 {
   if (node.Title == "Original Title")
   {
      node.Title = "New Title";
      node.Update();
      break;
   }
```

}

Otherwise try calling the $webs.Update() method